Update data in child component obtained by $slots
I'm using VueJS 3.4.25 and options API for this.
So I have these two components defined like this:
// ComponentA
<template>
...
<div ref="componentA">
  <slot></slot>
</div>
...
</template>
<script>
export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    fireComponentAMethod() {
      const slotNode = this.$slots.default()[0];
      slotNode.type.methods.fireComponentBMethod();
    },
  },
}
</script>

// ComponentB
<template>
...
isValueSet: {{ isValueSet }}
...
</template>
<script>
export default {
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      isValueSet: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    fireComponentBMethod() {
      console.log("I just fired fireComponentBMethod");
      this.isValueSet = true;
      console.log(this.isValueSet);
    },
  },
}
</script>

Ans somewhere else I set up the components in this manner:
// Some absolutely unrelated component
<ComponentA>
  <ComponentB />
</ComponentA>

The reasoning for this I'm aiming at greater reusability of the code, hence sometimes it's ComponentB, sometimes ComponentC and ComponentDoubleD inside ComponentA.
The problem is observed when fireComponentAMethod is fired. It indeed fires fireComponentBMethod and in the console I do see
I just fired fireComponentBMethod
true

But the change is not reflected in the ComponentB template, on the page it constantly stays isValueSet: false.
I tried using $refs to access the children, but I guess since they're in the slot, it doesn't work. For example, console.log(this.$refs) prints out this:
Proxy(Object) {componentA: div}
[[Target]]: Object
  componentA: div
    0: div

When calling this.$refs.componentA[0] it doesn't return a component instance. Instead, it returns an object representing a simple node... and I can't call any methods or change data on it.

"I tried using $refs" - what did you try? It's a mistake to call methods on vnode. Vnode is a blueprint to render a component, not component instance. There's no "this.isValueSet" in slotNode.type.methods.fireComponentBMethod(). Loose coupling may not be good design choice, it's unknown why "ComponentB, sometimes ComponentC and ComponentDoubleD inside ComponentA" is intended to be so flexible in your case. Probably there's a better way to do this. Any way, you need to get a ref of a comp in the slot first, then access the instance. Like that https://stackoverflow.com/a/78389222/3731501

@EstusFlask I updated my question to explain what I tried

I have been researching this some more, and thanks to @cantdocpp answer, cooked up the solution with provide/inject approached offered by Vue. Although to me this more looks like a workaround and a hack, it's the closest that I need.
// ComponentA
<template>
...
<div ref="componentA">
  <slot></slot>
  <button @click="fireComponentAMethod" />
</div>
...
</template>
<script>
import { computed } from "vue";

export default {
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      triggered: null,
    };
  },
  provide() {
    return {
      triggered: computed(() => this.triggered),
    };
  },
  methods: {
    fireComponentAMethod() {
      this.triggered = new Date();
    },
  },
}
</script>

// ComponentB
<template>
...
isValueSet: {{ isValueSet }}
...
</template>
<script>
export default {
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      isValueSet: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    fireComponentBMethod() {
      console.log("I just fired fireComponentBMethod");
      this.isValueSet = true;
      console.log(this.isValueSet);
    },
  },
  inject: ["triggered"],
  watch: {
    'triggered': function (n, o) {
      this.fireComponentBMethod();
    },
  },
}
</script>

Now this approach will change triggered on the button click and will trigger the update in ComponentB. I use new Date() to make sure the triggered value is always unique. This changes the values in data, which was the main goal.

I believe that calling a child component method from a parent is a no-go for most cases, even if you want to achieve high-level of reusability.
If your use cases is:
<ComponentA>
  <ComponentB />
</ComponentA>

Where <ComponentB /> can be replaced with <ComponentC /> or <ComponentD />, and it'll always be inside <ComponentA />. Then what you want to achieve is called COMPOUND COMPONENT pattern.
Quoting from Rethinking reusability with vue by alex vipond:

In a compound group of components, there is one parent component that manages most or all of that state, and there are descendant components that slot into the parent. Internally those descendants modify and watch the parent's state, ready to react to modification made by other descendants.

But the most important point is:

Also, the descendants can't be used outside of the parent component. Without the parent's reactive state, the descendants break

Now, I've seen many component library indeed use this kind of patterns. For example, this menu component by Headless UI is indeed use this kind of patterns. Where the parent manage almost all state and provide it to its children by heavily use scoped slots and provide & inject.
Also, Vue.js official documentation also have a similar section pattern called Renderless Components, which is a similar pattern that many UI Component library uses to achieve reusability.
So, for your use cases, you can leverage provide & inject to achieve similar reusability.
This example will use provide & inject, but you can also use scoped slots to achieve similar result:
// ComponentA.vue
<script setup>
import { provide } from 'vue'

function fireComponentAMethod() {
  alert('fire')
}

provide('componentAMethod', fireComponentAMethod)
</script>

<template>
  <slot></slot>
</template>

And ComponentB:
// ComponentB.vue
<script setup>
import { inject } from 'vue'

const componentAMethod = inject('componentAMethod')
</script>

<template v-slot="slotProps">
  <button @click="componentAMethod">Click Me</button>
</template> 

Here's a simple vue.js playground that use scoped slots and provide & inject to achieve similar results.

Thank you for the hint, the console logs do fire they way I'm doing it right now. The data does not update though... But I guess I'll have to rethink the whole thing with provide/inject...

Yes, provide/inject was created to solve this kind of issue in the first place. Most component library use them extensively
